# Finding extenal links/connections from a wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I downloaded some free wordpress themes online and also got some demo content online. After importing that demo content to wordpress theme, I modified my wordpress site for months. And everything looks ok.

The problem is, i downloaded that theme and demo content from a unknown site(i dont  know the exact url too, because i just searched and downloaded). And i doubt that contain some external link. ie... if my php files or demo content contain some malicious code, can anyone(the creator or theme or creator demo content) steal my info? is it possible? If it is possible how to check external connections from my php files and from demo content imported? Is there any plugins or any tools available for this?

Comment: Search the theme code for any obfuscated parts or weird calls to cURL, shell_exec or something like that. If you are not able to find anything not directly related to rendering the template then you can be fairly sure that there is no malicious code inside, save of course for the usual exploitable vulnerabilities like using unfiltered data.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk - Thanks for the info i'll check that. By the way is there any plugins or tools to find external links from a wordpress site?

Answer (score 0):

Wordfence is the best security plugin for WordPress. The basic version is free. Check out https://www.wordfence.com. You can use it to scan your files.

Backup your files and database before you install Wordfence.
Follow the instructions if you think your site has been hacked at https://www.wordfence.com/docs/how-to-clean-a-hacked-wordpress-site-using-wordfence/. You may also want to read the instructions at https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked for more tips.